# Date filter on Kendo UI Angular 2 Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using the `kendo-grid` from the Kendo UI Angular 2 library.  I would like to know if and how I can set a date filter - equivalent to the `boolean` and `numeric` values on the `filter` attribute below:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" filter="numeric">
</kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" filter="boolean">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Many thanks.

**Update as of 11th April 2017**

*From Telerik:*

"Currently there is not built-in date filter, as the DateInput component was not ready when the filter row functionality has been released. That said we will add such filter in some of the following releases"

Comment: are you wanting to apply a date pipe to the display field?

Comment: Hi Mast.  No it's just the ability to filter that I am after. Thanks.

Comment: Matt, the Date values are strings in the JSON response. Because, the Grid doesn't know when to parse the strings into Dates (there is no metadata telling the component that this particular field should be a date), **you will need to convert the date strings into Date objects**, before feeding the Grid.
P.S. Only strings, numbers and booleans are supported out-of-the-box, because these are the types in the JSON.

Comment: Yes, you could be right!. Maybe their problem is that the normal case is - receive JSON from web service & deserialize into JS, which as you said will only contain JSON types.  It would a bit of a nuisance then if you require the user to remap the entire object to convert certain strings to dates as you suggest.  They could allow JSON strings to be bound to date columns to combat this, but I guess for their client side implementation of process (@progress/kendo-data-query) to work they need a more general indication of the column type for sorting and filtering (not just filter="date").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge still Kendo UI not support date filter in angular-2, so you have to use custom filter.

Create custom filter with column type and set HTML5 input type according to that.

For normal string filter for date value do not specify any filter type in column.

```
<kendo-grid-column field="DateField">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: Hi Sandip.  Yes, I had a look through the source code and it looks like only string, boolean and numeric are supported at this time ... :(

Comment: There is built-in support for type="date" now:

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/filtering/#toc-filtering-basics

Answer (score 2):

you can filter date by below syntax in kendo-grid.

`<kendo-grid-column field="Bill-Date" title="Sales Date" filter="date">
 </kendo-grid-column>`

these is for additional : 
these shows filter by calendar animations.
add browser/animation file into your module.ts